# Скролл  в td таблицы

Tags: html, прокрутка, css

http://jsfiddle.net/wg7wby9q/5/

Как заставить **page** не вылазить за пределы **#settings**?

Просто `overflow:scroll` никак не влияет на высоту **page**, и поэтому он вылазит за границы родителя, который, в свою очередь, вылазит за **#settings**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалось найти ответ здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211309/overflowscroll-in-td

Если вкратце: верcткой не предусмотрен скролл для столбцов таблицы, поэтому выходом из этой ситуации является обертка содержимого моего td в див с `overflow:scroll` и `height:100%`.